# How to make a API call to Google-sheet, using jupyter notebook on the AWS ec2

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, google-sheets-api

#### I'm running it as a jupyter notebook on Amazon SageMaker.

-

- So I created a S3 Bucket and stored the json file(google-sheet credential) in there.
- I used Boto3 and I was able to crab the credential to the Jupyter notebook.
- Now when try to open the credential at `creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(result, scope)`

#### # It gives error, Expected string not dictonary

```
# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


# Call to S3 to retrieve the policy for the given bucket
result = s3.get_bucket_acl(Bucket='sheet-credentials')
print(result)


# Calling google sheet api

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(result, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("CALCULATOR").worksheet("hist")
google_sheet = sheet.get_all_records()

print(google_sheet)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sheet-credential.json'
```

It works on my local machine because I have `sheet-credential.json` file locally.

How do I get this file to my EC2 instance to be able to run the script?

Comment: @Michael Robellard